# MongoDB Add new field calculated from datetime and converted to int number

Tags: mongodb, datetime, type-conversion, integer, aggregation-framework

I'va a MongoDB collection (on **MongoDB v3.2.12**) with about **1 Billion records**.
The collection has a datetime key. I need to add a new key to the collection, derived from the datetime one, such as the value is **"yyyymmdd"** and save it as an **integer**.

For now with the following command I was able to create a duplicated collection with the new key as a string.

```
db.log.aggregate(
    [
        { "$addFields": { 
            "date_ref": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y%m%d", date: "$log_date" } } 
        }},
        { "$out": "log_test" }
    ]
)
```

Trying to add `NumberInt()` or `parseInt()` as following, didn't work.

```
db.log.aggregate(
    [
        { "$addFields": { 
            "date_ref": NumberInt( { $dateToString: { format: "%Y%m%d", date: "$log_date" } } )
        }},
        { "$out": "log_test" }
    ]
)
```

Using `NumberInt()` I get all values to 0.
Using `parseInt()` I get all values to 'NAN'.

I know I can use a new key and a `foreach` statement like this:

```
db.log_test.find().forEach( function (l) {
  l.date_ref_int = parseInt(l.date_ref); 
  db.log_test.save(l);
});
```

But this approach is very, very expensive in terms of time.
So, is it possible to do the conversion within the **aggregate**?

**UPDATE**

Another approach I tried was this:

```
db.log.aggregate(
    [
        { "$addFields": { 
            "date_ref_string": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y%m%d", date: "$log_date" } },
            "date_ref": NumberInt("date_ref_string") 
        }},
        { "$out": "log_test" }
    ]
)
```

I get no errors but the `"date_ref"` is always 0.

**UPDATE 2**

Following @Veeram suggestion I made this script:

```
db.log.aggregate(
    [
        { $addFields: 
            { "date_ref": 
                { $divide:
                    [
                        { $add:
                            [
                                { $multiply: [{"$year" : "$log_date"}, 10000000]}, 
                                { $multiply: [{"$month" : "$log_date"}, 100000]}, 
                                { $multiply: [{"$dayOfMonth" : "$log_date"}, 1000]}
                            ]
                        }, 1000
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        { "$out": "log_test" }
    ]
);
```

It works, but I get back values as `double`. I prefer an integer, because I need to build an index on that new calculated key and it would be smaller if the key is `integer` type.

Comment: What is your mongodb version ? Do you just need the date part converted to milliseconds ?

Comment: **MongoDB v3.2.12** in production, but 3.6 on my local testing machine. I don't want milliseconds but **the integer value** coming from `yyyymmdd`, such like 20180125.

Comment: Sorry, You cant change the type in aggregation pipeline https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6203

Comment: @Veeram Can you please see my question update and tell me if it can be used?

Comment: No that is not going to work as string to integer conversion is supported in aggregation framework.

Comment: You can use bulk write to improve the performance. @Veeram, it might be doable with the aggregation framework with some insane trick.

Comment: may be you can some math to transform the different datetime values into date number. `db.log.aggregate({$addFields:{date_ref:{$divide:[{$add:[{$multiply:[{"$year" : "$log_date"}, 10000000]}, {$multiply:[{"$month" : "$log_date"}, 100000]},{$multiply:[{"$dayOfMonth" : "$log_date"}, 1000]}]}, 1000]}}})`. Seems to be working with limited testing.

Comment: Tried your "mad math" solution and it worked! See the update on the question. But I get a `double`. I prefer an `integer`, because I need to build an index on that key and it would be smaller if the key is of `integer` type. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation query.

```
db.log.aggregate([
  {"$addFields":{
    "date_ref":{
      "$trunc":{
        "$divide":[
          {"$add":[
            {"$multiply":[{"$year":"$log_date"},10000000]},
            {"$multiply":[{"$month":"$log_date"},100000]},
            {"$multiply":[{"$dayOfMonth":"$log_date"},1000]}
          ]},
          1000
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Copy/Paste but it gives me this error: `2018-01-30T09:35:13.917+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] [src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13] Error: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.",
        "code" : 16410,
        "codeName" : "Location16410"
} : aggregate failed`

Comment: Can you try `db.log_test.find({date_ref: { $type: 16 }})` ? Are you looking in shell ?

Comment: I'm working with Robo 3T v1.1. The script instead is executed on MongoDB shell, loaded by a .js file.
With you command on the collection I get back 0 records.

Comment: Nevermind `$trunc` only retains the  integer part but still keeps the value as dobule value. Sorry looks like it is not possible..

Comment: Oh... so not what I want. I need the type to be integer, to reduce the index size on the new key and have better performance, since records are 1 Billion and more.